# CSS Help - How can a DIV ignore css previously set on the page?

Tags: css, html, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using AjaxControlToolkit CalendarExtender. Some previous rule in my stylesheet is affecting div's within the calendar.

```
div#paymentRegion div
{
    float:left;
    width:49%;
}
```

There are DIVs within the calendar that are being forced to 49%. How can I have the calendar ignore the previous settings and use the styles that come with the calendar? Is that possible? I am afraid to change the current rule, but I think it probably needs to be, however many other divs on this control rely on it. What does the > symbol do to a css rule. For example

```
div#paymentRegion > div
{
    float:left;
    width:49%;
}
```

Maybe that will help? I am open for any suggestions.
Thanks,
~ck in San Diego

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Theoretically**, the `>` symbol would select only `div`s that are immediate children of #paymentRegion.  A `div` nested farther down would be unaffected.  **However**, not all browsers interpret that correctly, so it's not something you can reliably use.

A more direct solution is to wrap your calendar in a `<div id="calendar">` and then write an overriding rule:

```
div#paymentRegion div {
    float: left;
    width: 49%;
}

div#calendar div {
    float: none;
    width: auto;
}
```

Now even though *most* `div`s inside #paymentRegion will be floated, the divs inside #calendar won't be!

Answer (score 1):

VoteyDisciple is right, since his proposed solution's rule has a higher specificity than your current one.

[More information on calculating specificity rules](http://htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/).

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to know what to suggest without any HTML. Can you tell us the basic structure? For example, is the `div` that is targeted in the first rule a direct child of `#paymentRegion`?

If it is the highest level `div` (not necessarily a direct child), and all other divs are below that one, you can try this:

```
div#paymentRegion div {
    float: left;
    width: 49%;
}

div#paymentRegion div div {
    float: none;
    width: auto;
}
```

However, the best bet would be to set a class/ID on that mysery `div`, if you can change your HTML.

```
div#paymentRegion div#uniqueID {
    float: left;
    width: 49%;
}
```