# Reportviewer displaying not properly when a style sheet is used

Tags: css, report-viewer2010

I am using **Report viewer** inside the **master page**.

When i display it. The **controls of the Reportviewer** are all over the place(part of display shown in figure)
[image]

After some debugging i found that the style sheet used in the master page is causing this. 
Below Tags when i remove from my style sheet the reports displays perfectly. 
Tags Removed

```
table
{
    width: 90%; 

color: #333333;
margin: 10px 10px 20px;
border-left: 1px solid #cbcbb4;
border-top: 1px solid #cbcbb4;

}

table caption 
{ 
    margin: 10px 0 5px; 
    font-weight: bold;
}

th, td
{
    right: 1px solid #cbcbb4;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #cbcbb4;
    padding: 2px 10px;
}
```

What is the solution?

Comment: Post you code please or give a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there would be one other than don't use tags in your style sheet that are really general. The Report Viewer Control builds a html table from the data, so the style sheet applied to the page will definitely affect this.

this may be helpful to you: [CSS Help - How can a DIV ignore css previously set on the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337653/css-help-how-can-a-div-ignore-css-previously-set-on-the-page)

Comment: You are right that Report Viewer Control builds a html table from the data but is happening to me . I am updating my question for interest.